# JQuery: hide and show with mvc not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a yes/no dropdown with a Kendo editor. The editor should hide on no selection and show on yes selection.

I have tried this so far. If someone could please point my mistake that will really help.
thanks

JQUERY:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[name='selectname']").change(function () {
            //alert($(this).val());
            if ($(selectitem).val() == "yes") {
                $('.yesnoitemselect').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.yesnoitemselect').hide();
            }
        });

    })
</script>
```

Razor code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <div id="selectitem" name="selectname">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DisplayNumber, new SelectList(Model.DropdownQuestions, "DisplayNumber", "ValueDescription"), "---Select One---")
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="yesnoitemselect" name="yesnoitemselect" id="yesnoitemselect">


                                    @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.Response)
            .Encode(false)
            .Name("Response")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px" })
            .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Content(true).Toolbar(true))
            .Tools(tools => tools.Clear()
            .Bold().Italic().Underline().JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
            .Formatting()
            .CleanFormatting()))


                        </div>
```

Comment: When you debug this, how does it fail?  It looks like you're using a non-existent variable here: `$(selectitem).val()`  Is there an error for that on the browser's debugging console?  Is the `change` handler invoked at all?  what is the value from that code?

Answer (score 0):

In your query selector you are using `selectitem` like it's a variable. You'll need to use a literal to get the element by id:

```
if ($('#selectitem').val() == "yes") {
```

An even easier way is to simply use `$this`:

```
if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
```

Comment: @David: I have added # symbol before selectitem, the problem is it dowsn't behave in an expected way, for the first time, when yes/no is hit the editor is hiding. We don't want that to happen, instead it should hide on no and show on yes. Also, when i debug the code it is never hitting if condition, instaed it defaults to else always. thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue.

I was passing incorrect parameter as value, once I fixed it the code is working now. Thought this will help someone else.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $('.yesnoitemselect').hide();
        $("#DisplayNumber").change(function () {

            if (this.value == '1') {   
                $('.yesnoitemselect').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.yesnoitemselect').hide();
            }
        });

    })
</script>
```